# Преобразование List в Map

Tags: java, структуры-данных

Есть такой класс

```
class MyClass {
    ............
    int getKey();
    ..........
}
```

Есть список этих объектов

```
List<MyClass> myList;
```

нужно объекты этого списка поместить в

```
Map<Integer, MyClass> myMap;
```

Есть что нибудь эффективней кроме

```
for (MyClass obj : myList)
    myMap.put(obj.getKey(), obj);
```

Также рассматривается вариант с наследованием от HashMap/TreeMap

Comment: имеете в виду по производительности? parallelStream() типа?

Comment: @Dred да. Типа того. Но для параллелизма тоже нужно знать минимальное количество элементов, на которых он начинает эффективно работать

Comment: myList.stream()/parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass::getKey,Function.identity()))

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Напишите ответом

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а сколько у вас объектов в листе? Я уверен, что производительность не поднимется, обычный foreach будет быстрее стримов. Параллельные стримы могут быть быстрее, но я не уверен что у вас настолько много элементов в листе(нужны тысячи). А если у вас мало элементов, то параллельный стрим будет медленнее обычного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через java8 Stream-API

```
myList
.stream() //parallelStream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass::getKey,Function.identity()))
```

Только учтите, что при таком подходе если будет дубликат ключей - то будет брошена ошибка IllegalStateException.

Comment: Только это не эффективнее.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и что понимается под эффективностью?

Comment: Ваш способ тратит чуть больше памяти и процессорного времени, чем обычный foreach.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы не ответили на вопрос. Возможно, автор имел в виду эффективнее с точки зрения кода ( о чем он как раз и указал в комментарии к вопросу)

Comment: _Dred: имеете в виду по производительности? Anton Shchyrov: Да, типа того._

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и ниже коммент "@AndrewBystrov Напишите ответом". Я считаю, что наша дискуссия ни к чему не приведет, так что предлагаю закончить ее